# Can callback defined in inline manner harm optimization, if it's defined on underlying element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In case when prop defined in inline style on React.Component - it causes redundant render calls when PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate used, no doubt about it. But what actually happens when it passed to React.Element?

E.g.

```
    <button
      onClick={() => {...}}
    >
      Click me.
    </button>
```

So, when Reconciliation happened it match this case:
https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#dom-elements-of-the-same-type

React will only update click handler(probably through `addEventListener`). Is it correct?

If it's so, it should be very cheap task. Should I care about creating persistent references for such kind of cases?

Comment: It recreates the function object in RAM on each render. But js does not need to recompile the function, just memcpy it in RAM. There's an overhead but it's too small to matter unless you're rendering literally tens of thousands of elements

Comment: yep, each render cases creating a new function, so it can influence the performance. But the reference to the old one func is not saved, so garbage collector should get rid of it.

Comment: Note that in theory there's an optimization for cases like this that a js engine can implement: rather than memcpy the function object just create a function reference object that points to the actual function object but with a different context (in ES standard terminology, a function's context is where the engine manages scopes and closures - yes, it overlaps with a different word "context" that means how the engine manages `this`). I don't really know if any engine does or does not do this though